# jQuery select all except elements under certain id?

Tags: jquery

```
$('body *').not("#submenu*").mouseover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
});

$('body *').not("#submenu *").mouseout(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

basically I want to avoid highlighting anything underneath the id 'submenu'. right now it seems to ignore the not selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your selector is missing a space.

```
$('body *').not("#submenu *").mouseover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
});

$('body *').not("#submenu *").mouseout(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hy9As/)

Comment: Using a `*` indicates you want ALL elements. Because you preface it with `#submenu`, it will find **ALL** elements within `#submenu`.